# how to include flash in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to include my flash in wordpress. i have a code in html.But i dont know how to include and where should i place ".swf" file and js files. Please help me

```
<div class="banner_flash">
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="358" height="180">
  <param name="movie" value="swf/flash1.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />

  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>--><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swf/flash1.swf" width="358" height="180">
    <![endif]<param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" /><param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" /><!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>--></object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: if your site will be viewed on mobile devices, dont use flash, it is being dropped in favour of javascript. something to consider in the long run. most things done in flash will have a js counterpart. sorry for being of no help to your question though

Answer (score 0):

Flash is slowly disappearing into obscurity, and is not supported on mobile devices any more. Therefore, I sugest that in future you look into html5 alternatives such as the video and canvas tags.

However, I understand that sometimes flash is a nesecary evil. I sugest you use one of the plugins available on he Wordpress plugin site. This looks like it might fit the bill:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/kimili-flash-embed/ or http://wordpress.org/plugins/top-flash-embed/

Comment: i need flash it be in header .

Comment: In that case you need to edit your themes header file. You can find this in the wp-content folder, under themes/[theme-name]/header.php

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that

- Your domain name is `http://www.example.com`
- Your flash folders are all inside a folder named `myflashfiles`

  - For example, inside `myflashfiles` would be a folder called `swf`, and inside that folder would be a file named `flash1.swf`

---

Upload the folder `myflashfiles` to your "root directory" -- this is the directory where you have Wordpress installed. There should already be at least 3 other directories inside that one:

- wp-admin
- wp-content
- wp-includes

You should now be able to go to `http://www.example.com/myflashfiles/swf/flash1.swf` and see your file appear.

Now, change your code to this:

```
<div class="banner_flash">
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="358" height="180">
  <param name="movie" value="/myflashfiles/swf/flash1.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="/myflashfiles/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />

  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>--><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/myflashfiles/swf/flash1.swf" width="358" height="180">
    <![endif]<param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" /><param name="expressinstall" value="/myflashfiles/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" /><!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>--></object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

HTH... :)

Comment: i have to add url of my site in value="https://example.com/myflashfiles" like that